# Androidアプリケーションのビルド

Tags: android

Androidアプリケーションのビルドが出来ません。
以下に詳細を記載する為、対処方法を教えてください。

１．ビルド → Androidアプリのビルド → リリースビルドを実施。
２．エイリアス、エイリアスのパスワードを入力。
３．下記のエラーメッセージが出力。
　　[エラーメッセージ]
　　ビルドに失敗しました。
　　アプリのビルドに失敗しました。ビルド設定に間違いがある可能性があります。
　　下記の設定を再確認してください: 
　　・AndroidManifest.xmlは正しく記述されていますか？
　　・キーストアの設定は正しいですか？
　　設定を修正した後、再度ビルドを実行してください。

ビルドの実施経緯は
アプリに更新が発生した為、ビルド作業を実施。
過去に同アプリをGoogleplayへアップロード済の為
バージョンは2.0.0に更新済。

以上、宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0):

> 過去に同アプリをGoogleplayへアップロード

このときの
キーストアを使いましたか？

そのキーストアが無いとバージョンアップはできません